# Query em embedded document

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Estou tentando fazer uma *query* para me retornar os investimentos somente do banco 1 e que não sejam poupança. Como faço? Já tentei várias maneiras e não deu certo até agora.

Segui a seguinte query:

```
db.Bancos.find( { "investimentos": { $elemMatch: { bank: "banco1", productName: {$ne:"Poupanca"} } } } );
```

```
{
  "_id": "5d3fc8c3914297c7b9a3a9e5",
  "banco": "banco 1",
  "investimentos": [{
      "bank": "banco1",
      "risk": "Conservador",
      "expiryDate": "2021-10-04",
      "tax": "1.02",
      "discriminator": "investment",
      "productName": "LCI"
    },

    {
      "bank": "banco1",
      "risk": "Conservador",
      "expiryDate": "2020-06-24",
      "tax": "0.75",
      "discriminator": "investment",
      "productName": "Fundo DI"
    },

    {
      "bank": "banco1",
      "risk": "Conservador",
      "tax": "0.04",
      "discriminator": "investment",
      "id": "259ad8ac-57b7-4d33-8e75-46cf5c5c28e3",
      "aniversary": "30",
      "productName": "Poupanca"
    }
  }]


  {
    "_id": "5d3fcb4c914297c7b9a3a9e6",
    "banco": "banco2",
    "investimentos": [{
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2020-06-24",
        "tax": "0.80",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "73db503f-c780-448c-a6a8-05d2837ff6ff",
        "redemptionDate": "D+1",
        "productName": "Fundo DI"
      }

      ,
      {
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2020-12-17",
        "tax": "0.98",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "54e01515-dc7f-470f-8f00-8603c8f00686",
        "productName": "LCA"
      },

      {
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2021-08-05",
        "tax": "1.0",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "259ad8ac-57b7-4d33-8e75-46cf5c5c28e2",
        "productName": "CDB"
      }
    }]
```

Comment: Assim fica impossível ajudar. Monte um exemplo [mínimo, completo e verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Ou seja: forneça, pelo menos, como sua query e sua collection estão estruturadas.

Comment: Pronto, melhorei, desculpas.

Answer (score 1):

Bom dia Luan. Para fazer essa consulta, é que você utilize o aggregation framework que o banco de dados te oferece, com isso você consegue filtrar dentro dos nested documents.

Segue a query.

**Objetos do banco:**

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5d3fc8c3914297c7b9a3a9e5",
    "banco": "banco 1",
    "investimentos": [
      {
        "bank": "banco1",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2021-10-04",
        "tax": "1.02",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "productName": "LCI"
      },
      {
        "bank": "banco1",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2020-06-24",
        "tax": "0.75",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "productName": "Fundo DI"
      },
      {
        "bank": "banco1",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "tax": "0.04",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "259ad8ac-57b7-4d33-8e75-46cf5c5c28e3",
        "aniversary": "30",
        "productName": "Poupanca"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "_id": "5d3fcb4c914297c7b9a3a9e6",
    "banco": "banco2",
    "investimentos": [
      {
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2020-06-24",
        "tax": "0.80",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "73db503f-c780-448c-a6a8-05d2837ff6ff",
        "redemptionDate": "D+1",
        "productName": "Fundo DI"
      },
      {
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2020-12-17",
        "tax": "0.98",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "54e01515-dc7f-470f-8f00-8603c8f00686",
        "productName": "LCA"
      },
      {
        "bank": "banco2",
        "risk": "Conservador",
        "expiryDate": "2021-08-05",
        "tax": "1.0",
        "discriminator": "investment",
        "id": "259ad8ac-57b7-4d33-8e75-46cf5c5c28e2",
        "productName": "CDB"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

**Query:**

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        $match:
        {
            'investimentos.bank':'banco1'
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            banco: 1,
            investimentos:{
                $filter{
                    'input': '$investimentos',
                    'as': 'item',
                    'cond': {
                        $ne: ['$$item.productName', 'Poupanca']
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline)
```

**Para mais informações, consulte:**

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/

https://university.mongodb.com/

**Para testar o código sem ter própriamente um banco de dados:**

https://mongoplayground.net/

Dúvidas, fico à disposição.